# program asking for the name and searching for the number associated to that name

Tags: python-3.x

```
def name_number():
    name=input("Give the name for the new contact: ")
    number=input("Give the number for the new contact: ")
    return name
def directory():
    search=input("Input the name you want to search in the directory: ")
    print ("Number for Harry Callahan is", search)
ans=True
while ans:
    print("Phone book ver. 1.0.1")
    print("1) Add new number to the directory")
    print("2) Search for a contact")
    print("0) Quit")
    ans=input("What would you like to do?: ") 
    break
    if ans=="1":
        x = str(name_number())
    elif ans=="2":
        directory(x)
    elif ans=="0":
        break
```

I am writing this code. But I am just getting this much output and nothing is working after that

Phone book ver. 1.0.1

1) Add new number to the directory

2) Search for a contact

0) Quit

What would you like to do?: 1

Comment: What did you expect? What did you get instead?

Comment: `name_number` never does anything with `number`. Are you intending to return that as well?

Comment: Why do you have a `break` after `ans=input("What would you like to do?: ")`? That's causing the loop to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop will only run once (and not even once all the way to the end of it) because you explicitly break after asking "What would you like to do", and the program will end...

```
while ans:
    print("Phone book ver. 1.0.1")
    print("1) Add new number to the directory")
    print("2) Search for a contact")
    print("0) Quit")
    ans=input("What would you like to do?: ") 
    break                                          # <-- breaking here 
    if ans=="1":
        x = str(name_number())
    elif ans=="2":
        directory(x)
    elif ans=="0":
        break
```

In other words, your program is effectively equal to this:

```
print("Phone book ver. 1.0.1")
print("1) Add new number to the directory")
print("2) Search for a contact")
print("0) Quit")
ans=input("What would you like to do?: ")
```